# Part of the TimePicker is cropped in landscape

Tags: java, android

TimePicker is working fine for me, except in landscape view, where it is either cropped a bit from the right not showing the whole clock, or the clock is not even visible, just giving me the background colors (left is pink and right is white) instead. Tried to look for solutions all came back as "don't set a title", I didn't set a title, even tried setting the title as null, didn't work.

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TimePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_time_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TimePicker>
```

called using these lines

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
TimePickerFragment dialog =
        TimePickerFragment.newInstance( mTimeString );
dialog.setTargetFragment( NewBlockFragment.this, REQUEST_TIME );
dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_TIME);
```

and the timepicker class

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_TIME = "com.x";
    private static final String ARG_TIME = "time";

    private TimePicker mTimePicker;

    public static TimePickerFragment newInstance(String time) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_TIME, time);
        TimePickerFragment fragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String time = getArguments().getString(ARG_TIME);
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(time.split(":", -1)[0]);
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(time.split(":", -1)[1]);

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_time, null);

        mTimePicker = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_time_picker);
        mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mTimePicker.setHour(hour);
            mTimePicker.setMinute(minute);
        } else {
            mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
            mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
        }

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        int hour;
                        int minute;

                        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            hour = mTimePicker.getHour();
                            minute = mTimePicker.getMinute();
                        } else {
                            hour = mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
                            minute = mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
                        }

                        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, hour + ":" + minute);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                .create();
    }

    private void sendResult(int resultCode, String time) {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, time);
        getTargetFragment()
                .onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

Main logcat exceptions I get

```
09-22 13:04:25.847 1784-2256/com.android.systemui E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7fb429023080
09-22 13:04:25.853 2825-2825/com.x D/android.widget.GridLayout: horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=503, x2-x1>=816, x2-x0<=864 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x0<=864
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try to this :

```
timePicker.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Tried it with mTimePicker right before the return statement, no luck, still same problem

Comment: are you setting title of TimePiceker somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.<YOUR_XML_FILE_NAME>);
```

Change below code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
setContentView(R.layout.<YOUR_XML_FILE_NAME>);
}
```

Comment: still same issue unfortuantely

Comment: the only two lines looking weird are those

09-22 13:04:25.847 1784-2256/com.android.systemui E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7fb429023080
09-22 13:04:25.853 2825-2825/com.x D/android.widget.GridLayout: horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=503, x2-x1>=816, x2-x0<=864 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x0<=864.

Comment: can't find a setcontentview for fragments, also the second code block you are mentioning, this oncreate method is not in the dialogfragment overridable functions.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by totally changing the "timepickerfragment.java" code, still not sure what was wrong with the first one, but here it is for anyone that doesn't want to spend the next four days looking for answer that I couldn't find on several asking boards

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    public static final String EXTRA_TIME =
            "com.x.time";
    private static final String ARG_TIME = "time";

    private TimePicker mTimePicker;

    public static TimePickerFragment newInstance(String time) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_TIME, time);
        TimePickerFragment fragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String time = getArguments().getString(ARG_TIME);
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(time.split(":", -1)[0]);
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(time.split(":", -1)[1]);

        // TODO this for 24-hours, make the final false for AM/PM or make it variable
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }

    private void sendResult(int resultCode, String time) {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, time);
        getTargetFragment()
                .onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```